# Testing objects that reference other objects in minitest & ruby

Tags: ruby, oop, reference, minitest

I am having trouble testing methods similar to this using minitest where objects have references to other objects:

```
def drive num
    old_place = @current_place.name
    if num == 0
        road = @current_place.first_place_road
        @current_place = @current_place.first_place
    else
        road = @current_place.second_place_road
        @current_place = @current_place.second_place
    end
    print_drive(old_place, road)
end
```

I am trying to test by creating 2 mock objects, and stubbing their methods to return the other mock.

```
def test_drive_to_first_place

    start_place = Minitest::Mock.new
    end_place = Minitest::Mock.new

    def start_place.name; "first place"; end
    def start_place.first_place; end_place; end
    def start_place.first_place_road; "road"; end

    def end_place.name; "end place"; end
    def end_place.first_place; nil; end
    def start_place.first_place_road; nil; end


    driver = Driver::new "driver", start_place

    driver.drive(0)

    assert_output(stdout = ......
end
```

I am getting this error and Im not sure how to approach it. The objects im testing do not have any property or method :end_place, it is just used as a name in testing.

```
1) Error:
DriverTest#test_drive_to_first_place:
NoMethodError: unmocked method :end_place, expected one of []
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct format to set a required response would be ...

```
start_place.expect(:first_place, end_place)
```

If you define a method, you don't have access to variables defined outside the method, so your `def start_place.first_place...` code can't work.